# How to get function parameters when the function have an type variable <T>?

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript function as below:

```
function test<T>(func: (thing: T) => {}) {
}
```

How can I defined anther function's type as some parameters as the 'test' function?

current typescript version is 3.5.1.If necessary I will change.

I know typescript have an type function `Parameters` that I can use for an normal function without `<T>`.
as below:

```
function normalFun(a: string, b: string) {

}

function newNormalFun(...args: Parameters<typeof normalFun>) {
// now typeof args is [string,string]
}
```

But it is useless for the `test` function with `<T>`.

The Parameters function:

```
//from typescript lib.es5.d.ts
type Parameters<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;
```

It use the `infer` to get the target.
Is there an method to infer an function's type with an knowed T?

Comment: Nope, no syntax for that. If `T` has constraints, the `Parameters` type will extract parameters as if `T` were the constraint but you can't do it for a particular `T`

Comment: Can you give a usage example of how you would like to use the feature if it existed. For instance, how does your use case differ from what I wrote in the playground here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgCoD4AUokAXIvlABYxgDmp2AlIgLy6IDeAvk+4pwLAAoItHhIwKAO7Z0UAGLh8AOhUBDAE400pAAobVAWxSp1aTFACeABxRxgyWbh58hE6bIVh85KrSasyLgYGAG4gA

Comment: I am trying to create an decorator `pre` for `mongoose.Schema.prototype.pre` function.The input parameters should similar with it [mongoose.Schema.prototype.pre](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongoose/index.d.ts#L779).Hope that, I can quote it ,not copy it .